# Having trouble getting date and time in C. I've searched for answers and tried many but none work,

Tags: c, date, time

My assignment is to use unix system calls or library utilities in C to get an answer, and I've been searching for a while, All the answers available seem to lead to something with localtime() or time strftime() and I keep getting these warnings that say the functions are unsafe. I've been trying examples and copy pasting code but nothing seems to compile usually with the unsafe error. Help. Extra details, I can't use any libraries out of the very standard ones, things like chrono have gotten my friend rejected work before.

Comment: When you get these "unsafe function" warnings, you don't get a suggestion to a function which *is* safe? Like e.g. [`localtime_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a442x3ye.aspx) or [`localtime_r`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime_r.3.html)? And as always when you have questions regarding compiler/linker errors or warnings, please include the *complete* and *unedited* error log in the question.

Comment: You can suppress the warnings (on VS _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS) or use the same calls with the _s suffix.

Answer (score 0):

If you're required to turn in the work using the 'traditional' library functions like strftime(), then you'll need to turn off the warnings about these functions being unsafe.

There's usually some way to do this, but it will depend what specific compiler you're using, and you didn't say.

There's nothing particularly 'wrong' with solutions using these functions, it's just that times have moved on since they were originally developed, and many people try to avoid the potential security risks associated with their use.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using whats available in the time header? As far as I know, the time.h header should be available to any C compiler.

Some more information to read up on:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_date_and_time_functions

Comment: He's saying that when he uses these he gets a warning about them being 'unsafe'